# how to do "nowrap" on a vertical list of DIVs

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm using a list of inline-block DIVs:

```
<div class="row" style="border:1px solid;width:40%;overflow:hidden">
  <div style="display:inline-block">A</div>
  <div style="display:inline-block">B</div>
  <div style="display:inline-block">C</div>
  <div style="display:inline-block">D</div>
  <div style="display:inline-block">E</div>
  <div style="display:inline-block">F</div>
</div>
```

See [jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GbBZ6/3/)

When I resize the browser the list keep the same spaces between letters, but when I resizing it to be too small the letters start to wrap.

1. How can I force nowrap on the list
2. How can I scatter the letters evenly to take the full extent of the parent width?

Answer (score 0):

1. use `display:table-cell` , it will not wrap.
2. give all of them a `width` of around 15%,

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GbBZ6/6/)

Comment: I still have problem with question 2. When I resize the windows, in the example to the right, the letters are not scatter evenly ( F is not align with right border )

Comment: @user3369398 You can achieve this by setting the parent's display to `display:table` and have all the children with `display:table-cell` have `text-align:center`. See http://jsfiddle.net/GbBZ6/9/

Answer (score 0):

1) Set a height on the parent container (which has overflow hidden) - this way - visually - the letters won't wrap.

2) Use `text-align:justify` with a pseudo element to justify the letters.

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/GbBZ6/8/)**

```
.row
{
    border:1px solid;
    width:40%;
    height: 18px;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-align:justify;
}
.row:after
{
    content:'';
    display:inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}
.row div
{
    display:inline-block;
}
```